# access cabal's "exposed-modules" from test suite via Distribution package

Tags: haskell, cabal

given `example.cabal`:

```
exposed-modules:
 A.B
 A.B.C
```

can I import a `exposedModules` from `Distribution.Something` where:

```
>>> exposedModules >>= print
["A.B","A.B.C"]
```

the use case is `doctest`, which takes a list of modules/files, non-recursively. I could:

```
main = do
 exposedModules >>= doctest
```

I checked its reverse dependencies (http://packdeps.haskellers.com/reverse/doctest), and it looks like lens does it manually (https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.7/src/tests/doctests.hsc).

and hoogling for `exposedModules`, I can't see how to get the "current" package's `Library` (https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%2Bcabal+exposedModules).

Answer (score 0):

Using `Distribution.PackageDescription.Parse` you can call `readPackageDescription` to get your package's description, and then from `condLibrary` extract the `exposedModules` section.